# Check more then one criteria before updating Pardot prospect or adding new one

Tags: form, pardot

I have some issue about updating prospect. Pardot Form Handler is checking the prospect before inserting it as new or updating an old one. No problem at this. I want it to update prospect if there was already same mail address. But I don't want to check only the mail address. I also want to check one more item. If both mail and (that) item is same. Then update the matching prospect. But let's say email address is same but the selected form item(example: name) is different. Then I want it insert it as new prospect.

But couldn't find the add this criteria in Pardot. Is it possible to do this? How can I add more criteria to update existing prospect or add a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to use the Prospect Query API and specify an email address as criteria.

You could try to use the `read` endpoint, you will get EITHER a single object (if only one prospect is found) OR you will get an array of Prospects if multiple are found with the same email address. You could then search these results looking for a match (or lack of a match).

If Pardot and all pertinent prospects are synced to Salesforce, you could try searching Salesforce for Contacts/Leads that match all your criteria. If you find a good match you could look up the Prospect via CRM id, and if there is no match you can safely perform your Pardot update.